# In the V8 Javascript Engine, how do you add a FunctionTemplate as an attribute of another FunctionTemplate with the C++ API?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I have a function set up to return a wrapped C++ object when called as

```
new MyClass();
```

but I want to also be able to say

```
MyClass.do_something();
```

I know how to do what I want in pure javascript:

```
MyClass.prototype = { do_something: function(){}};
```

but how do I do the same in C++?

I'm aware of the InstanceTemplate() and PrototypeTemplate() methods on v8::FunctionTemplate, but those seem to only be used in the creation of the new object returned when `new MyClass()` is called.   How do I get at the actual function's prototype?

Thank you.

I saw this post, but am not sure if it's relevant: [Add a function template to a global object prototype in v8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565483/add-a-function-template-to-a-global-object-prototype-in-v8)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491385/how-is-asynchronous-javascript-interpreted-and-executed-in-node-js

Comment: I don't see anything in there that's specifically answering my question.   All I see is "use templates" which I already am: "I'm aware of the InstanceTemplate() and PrototypeTemplate() methods on v8::FunctionTemplate"

Comment: I think I was way overthinking this.  You just call .Set on the function template.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: yeah, that was more of a guess before.  But now that I've confirmed, I've self answered.   I seem to do that a lot in the [v8] tag.  Now I just need to remember to come back and accept the answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was way overthinking the problem.

You simply call .Set() on your v8::FunctionTemplate and pass in another v8::FunctionTemplate as the value.

```
my_constructor_function_template.Set("static_method_name", static_method_function_template);
```